# Запрос на Добавление записей в БД

Tags: c#, sql, запрос, linq

У меня в таблице есть 5 столбцов, первый это индекс, который сам прибавляется.

Как написать запрос чтобы он отправлял только 4 других столбца?

```
    private void butTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(MainWindow.connectionString); // создаем подключение
        conn.Open(); // открываем подключение
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format("Insert Into ListOfCriminalCases(NumberCriminalCases,Article,DateIntination,DateAdded) Values (@text1, @text2, @picker1, @curtime"), conn); // создаем SQL запрос
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("text1", textBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("text2", textBox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("picker1",dateTimePicker1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("curtime",MainWindow.currentDate);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // выполняем запрос на сервер
        conn.Close(); // закрываем соединение
    }
```

В чем ошибся? и можно ли так вообще?

[image: Ошибка]

Comment: Разумеется, если у вас поле с ключом - то можно писать запросы, чтобы не указывать это поле. А на скрине у вас ругается совсем на другое - на то, что вы передаёте поле с датой не в том формате.

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("picker1",dateTimePicker1.Text);` ==> `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("picker1",dateTimePicker1.Value);`

Comment: @AK нет изменение с Text на Value не помогло.

Comment: @tym32167 А что не так с пикером? Ругается не на пикер, а на куртайм.

Comment: @tym32167 Да это не важно, и на пикер ругается тоже. =(

Comment: @AK хм, я подумал, что автор зря передает дату текстом, так как она будет хз как отформатирована и это может быть проблемой

Comment: ну и я точно не помню, но разве @ не надо указывать и в параметрах тоже? Типа `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("picker1",dateTimePicker1.Text);` ==> `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@picker1",dateTimePicker1.Value);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел ошибку. Просто не закрыл скобку в запросе Values
Все работает. Все норм записывает.
Как и планировалось 4 поля ввожу сам, а первый с индексом сам добавляет +1.
 Рабочий пример)

```
    private void butTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(MainWindow.connectionString); // создаем подключение
        conn.Open(); // открываем подключение
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format("Insert Into ListOfCriminalCases(NumberCriminalCases,Article,DateIntination,DateAdded) Values (@text1, @text2, @picker1, @curtime)"), conn); // создаем SQL запрос
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("text1", textBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("text2", textBox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("picker1",dateTimePicker1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("curtime", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // выполняем запрос на сервер
        conn.Close(); // закрываем соединение
    }
```

Может кто знает как при удалении записи сделать чтобы в sql индекс понимал что -1 запись, а то когда после удалении записи добавляем новую запись индекс идет дальше?

Comment: автоинкрементное поле всегда идет дальше, ему без разницы, что вы удалете

Comment: Удаление может быть где-то из середины и как тогда избежать коллизии ключа при вставке? Постоянно обходить в поисках "окон" или держать в памяти список свободных номеров? Можно такую дичь на триггерах сделать. Но если речь идет о каких-то упорядоченных списках, то это стоило бы делать на уровне бизнес-логики, а не полагаться на автоинкремент.

Comment: @free_ze спасибо. Мне удаление не нужно в этой проге. На будущее хотел узнать )